# Optimise repeat searches using sqlite3

Tags: python, performance, search, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 in python 2.7.3 to create and search through a database (my_db) as follows:

```
c.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_db WHERE entry LIKE ?', (t+'%',))
print c.fetchone()
```

The database has roughly `2.44e8` entries and will be searched at least `1e6` times.

The search is successful however I find everything slowing down and after roughly `7e3` searches it is positively crawling.

**As the program is cycling through the query terms I'm leaving the database open - is this a mistake? Or is there an alternative reason for this slowing?**

Comment: I Believe sqlite3 stores all data in memory as you process. The more data and longer you process, the more memory it is hogging. Try using MySql or Posgres instead. Edit: Check Out SqlAlchemy it's a really robust cool sql manipulation module

Comment: To optimize every single query, you need a COLLATE NOCASE index on the column. However, there should be no change in speed over time. Is there an increase in memory usage over time?

Comment: @Busterdust - if that is the case, is there a way to clear the memory at defined intervals?

Comment: @CL - thank you! Once again you have been very helpful. Although with my rudimentary (and that's being kind) understanding of the topic I see I have a lot of reading to do!